# Confirm dialog box while using HTML5 pointer lock API

Tags: javascript, pointerlock

I am trying out [pointer lock API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_Lock_API) using this [demo page](http://mdn.github.io/pointer-lock-demo/). But while running the code I am seeing that browser is showing a confirmation dialog box asking whether user wants to hide the mouse pointer. Is there any way to prevent this dialog box from appearing programmatically so that users have seamless experience ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question might be too broad, since it actually strongly depends on the implementation, i.e. the particular browser. That’s already a faint clue to a “no”.

Other web APIs like [`getUserMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia) or [`getCurrentPosition()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition) or [`requestFullscreen()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullscreen) also require a confirmation, and it might be very much intended that way. The user should retain control at any time. Especially with a pointer-lock, an unexperienced user could easily be trapped. That’s another strong hint for “no”.

In some browsers (like Firefox), you can click “always allow” in order not to be asked again for that domain. You can even set global flags: regarding WebRTC, for instance, you could set `media.navigator.permission` in Firefox or `media-stream-camera` in Chrome. While you could lead users to do so, it might be additional evidence that you can’t programmatically to this, hence another “no”.

What do the specs say? Not much about high-level permission-asking. They rather define what happens right after permission or denial. While [*Geolocation*](http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/#get-current-position) and [*Fullscreen*](https://fullscreen.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-element-requestfullscreen) don’t, [*Media Capture*](http://www.w3.org/TR/mediacapture-streams/#dom-mediadevices-getusermedia) at least mentions that the method “prompts the user for permission”.

There doesn’t seem to be a chance that one day you can prevent the permission request by code. It does seem we have to stick to other means to deliver a seamless experience, like a sensual first-time explanation or a tutorial that encourages users to always grant permission.